# 'Named Singleton' with Google Guice

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

i try to implement `'@Named'` injection but i do not want to predefine the @Named instances (i have an example at the end, which is actually working... but not the way i want - as i predefine the names)

its easier to provide an code example than explaining what i mean.

```
public class NamedSingletonExample {
    private static Map<String, DoubleProperty> dMap = new HashMap<String, DoubleProperty>();

    public static DoubleProperty getNamedDoubleProperty(String name) {
        DoubleProperty d = dMap.get(name);
        if (d == null) {
            d = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
            dMap.put(name, d);
        }
        return d;
    }

    @Test
    public void testNamedSingleton() {
        System.out.println("test()");
        DoubleProperty d0 = getNamedDoubleProperty("d0");
        DoubleProperty d1 = getNamedDoubleProperty("d1");
        DoubleProperty d0_2 = getNamedDoubleProperty("d0");
        d0.set(1);
        d1.set(2);
        d0_2.set(4);

        System.out.println("expected: false & actual -> " + (d0.get() == d1.get()));
        System.out.println("expected: true  & actual -> " + (d0.get() == d0_2.get()));
        System.out.println("expected: true  & actual -> " + (d0 == d0_2));
    }
}
```

and this is the way i expect it to work using `guice`

```
public class NamedSingletonConsumer {

    @Inject
    public NamedSingletonConsumer(//
            @Named("d0") DoubleProperty d0, //
            @Named("d1") DoubleProperty d1, //
            @Named("d0_2") DoubleProperty d0_2//
    ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

i read loads of in other questions here on `StackOverflow` and used google (including `guice` doc) but was not able to find an example for this.

now the "working" example:

```
public class AllInOneExample {

    public AllInOneExample() {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AllInOneExample.DoublePropertyModule());
        DoublePropertyConsumer consumer = injector.getInstance(DoublePropertyConsumer.class);
        consumer.test();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AllInOneExample();
    }

    static class DoublePropertyConsumer {

        DoubleProperty d0;
        DoubleProperty d1;
        DoubleProperty d0_2;

        @Inject
        public DoublePropertyConsumer(//
                @Named("d0") DoubleProperty d0, //
                @Named("d1") DoubleProperty d1, //
                @Named("d0_2") DoubleProperty d0_2//
        ) {
            this.d0 = d0;
            this.d1 = d1;
            this.d0_2 = d0_2;
        }

        public void test() {
            System.out.println("test()");
            d0.set(1);
            d1.set(2);
            d0_2.set(4);

            System.out.println("expected: false & actual -> " + (d0.get() == d1.get()));
            System.out.println("expected: true  & actual -> " + (d0.get() == d0_2.get()));
            System.out.println("expected: true  & actual -> " + (d0 == d0_2));
        }
    }

    static class DoublePropertyFactory {

        private Map<String, DoubleProperty> dMap = new HashMap<String, DoubleProperty>();

        public DoubleProperty buildProperty(String name) {
            DoubleProperty d = dMap.get(name);
            if (d == null) {
                d = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
                dMap.put(name, d);
            }
            return d;
        }
    }

    static class DoublePropertyModule extends AbstractModule {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            DoublePropertyFactory doublePropertyFactory = new DoublePropertyFactory();

            requestInjection(doublePropertyFactory);

            // bind(DoubleProperty.class).annotatedWith(Named.class).toInstance(doublePropertyFactory .buildProperty(???)));
            bind(DoubleProperty.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("d0"))
                    .toInstance(doublePropertyFactory.buildProperty("d0"));
            bind(DoubleProperty.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("d1"))
                    .toInstance(doublePropertyFactory.buildProperty("d1"));
            bind(DoubleProperty.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("d0_2"))
                    .toInstance(doublePropertyFactory.buildProperty("d0"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The benefit of predefining the names is that Guice can tell you whether you've satisfied all of your bindings. If you don't want that, and you have an arbitrary number of bindings, why not just inject a `Map<String, Double>` and pull out the properties you need?

Comment: this is actually what i am doing now. but another solution would save some lines of code. and it would be nicer to have in the code